# Autoplay Images in Accompanist Pager

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, coil

I'm implementing an horizontal pager with Accompanist. Is there an elegant way to automatically switch the images every 5 seconds?

Otherwise, I'd have to fake a manual swipe by using a channel in the viewmodel that increments the currentPage every 5 seconds.. which, to be honest, I'm not quite a fan of.

Before Compose, I used to implement the [Why Not Image Carousel](https://github.com/ImaginativeShohag/Why-Not-Image-Carousel), which has a built-in autoplay property.

Any help would be appreciated. Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
val images = // list of your images...

val pageState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = images.size)
HorizontalPager(state = pageState) {
  // Your content...
}

// This is the interesting part, when your page changes,
// the LaunchedEffect will run again
LaunchedEffect(pageState.currentPage) {
    delay(3000) // wait for 3 seconds.
    // increasing the position and check the limit
    var newPosition = pageState.currentPage + 1
    if (newPosition > images.lastIndex) newPosition = 0
    // scrolling to the new position.
    pageState.animateScrollToPage(newPosition)
}
```

Here is the result (in the GIF, the interval is 1 sec):

[image]